# Проблема с XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xmlhttprequest

У меня проблема с XMLHttpRequest. 
Необходимо получать данные со страницы при каждом запуске программы.
Однако, по видимому, запрос кешируется и программе выдаются данные из кэша, а не со страницы.

```
var news;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/data/news.json");
xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status != 200) return;
    news = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
}
xhr.send(null);
```

Результат всегда один и тот же, хотя /data/news.json содержит другие данные.

Comment: Попробуйте установить заголовок кеширования, хотя сам по себе файл на сервер не должен кешироваться. `xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Через Cache-Control header:
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0");

// Хак для IE и более старых браузеров:
xhr.setRequestHeader("Expires", "Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT");
```

Либо как альтернатива, можете добавлять случайные числа в параметры

```
xhr.open("GET", "/data/news.json?_=" + new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: Ни один из способов не заработал. Как выдавал одно и то же, так и выдает.

Comment: @Nikita В Network включите "Disable cache" и попробуйте еще раз, если повторится, проблема где-то в коде

Comment: Это WSH, тут нет DevTools

Comment: UPD: заработало, просто надо было сделать вот так:
`xhr.open("GET", "/data/news.json?_=" + new Date().getTime(), false);`